# Tagging any Users on Discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a question about tagging any user on discord. For example, how can I tag a user when they get something rare and I say lucky! (ie. the bot will say "lucky! @user")

Here is my code:

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content == "lucky!") {
        const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/48/af/d0/48afd0510b98ad1202daaee5bf28bc4c.gif');
        message.channel.send(attachment)
    }

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

})
```

Comment: You can use `<@id>` for users or `<#id>` for channels. More details here : https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html

Comment: Is there a way to put it in the program I made? When I typed lucky! @{user} it didn't post the gif attachment. If I were to skip the code, I would mention the user with <@id> in one post and then type lucky! in the second to have the gif appear :/ but it would look nicer on one line. Is the code from the link you sent updated according to the latest version of vsc?

Answer (score 1):

You can reply with the `GuildMember` / `User` object and your bot will mention the user.

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    message.channel.send(`Lucky! ${message.author}`)
    // --> Lucky! @User
});
```

You can use `message.reply()` too.

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    message.reply("Lucky!")
   // --> @User, Lucky!
});
```